# How to pass hashes over questions.yaml in Rancher

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher

I try to pass a hash thru my questions.yaml in rancher UI.

This is how my hash is defined in **values.yaml**

```
my-app:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations: {"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range": "0.0.0.0/0", "kubernetes.io/tls-acme": "true"}
```

in my **questions.yaml** i have defined this question:

```
- variable: my-app.ingress.annotations
  label: Ingress Annotations
  type: string
```

The **ingress.yaml** needs to iterate every element

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
{{- with .Values.my-app.ingress.annotations }}
{{ toYaml . | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
```

The String I entered in the UI was as follow:

> {"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range": "0.0.0.0/0", "kubernetes.io/tls-acme": "true"}

But this causes this error after deploying it :

> Failed to install app my-app. Error: UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse
> error on my-app/templates/ingress.yml: error converting
> YAML to JSON: yaml: line 11: did not find expected key

My guess is, it is interpreted as string and therefore can not be iterated.

Is there a proper way to pass hashes thru questions.yaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `ingress.yaml` like following

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    {{- with .Values.my-app.ingress.annotations }}
  {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }} #<-- change here
  {{- end }}
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
```

According to the [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/)

> `{{-` (with the dash and space added) indicates that whitespace should be chomped left,

then use `nindent` to avoid manual spacing

> `nindent` is almost identical to `indent`, but begins a new line.

Comment: Can you add some detail about why the indentation, the `{{-`, and the `nindent` changes solve the issue?